# OSGI EventAdmin can not send event - getting null point exception on Producer

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

I am trying to send an event to a consumer. I am getting NullPointerException

Here is my event code

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    EventAdmin eventAdmin;
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("started");
        Dictionary<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
        properties.put("test", "blah");
        Event event = new Event("test/sent", properties);
        System.out.println("sending");
        eventAdmin.sendEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("stopped ");
    }
}
```

Here is the LOG

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   com.aml.project.Activator.start() of bundle h.    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:439)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:739)    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:599)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:526)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:415)
>     at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:416)     at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)    at
>   org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.aml.project.Activator.start(Activator.java:21)    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:552)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
>     ... 23 more java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3):

You use the field eventAdmin that is never set. So you get a NullPointerException. I suggest to use declarative services instead and inject EventAdmin using @Reference.

See [OSGi Event Admin – Publish & Subscribe](http://blog.vogella.com/2017/05/16/osgi-event-admin-publish-subscribe/) from Vogella for all details.